# stylus import: выбрать кроме файлов с суффиксом

Tags: css, регулярные-выражения, импорт, stylus

Есть `.styl` файл, который импортирует все другие файлы с определенных папок. Как верно задать правило для включения всех, кроме некоторых файлов, с суффиксом, например, `*-ie.style`?

```
import(['../moduls/*', '!../moduls/*-ie.styl'])
```

Приведенный выше код не работает.

Можно ли внутри импорта записать подобие regexp, например:

```
import('../moduls/+(*|!*-ie.*)')
```

Comment: Поменять местами элементы массива не пробовал? Т. е. сначала запретить, а потом разрешить.

Comment: @Qwertiy
оно вообще такой массив не читает... это просто псевдокод -пример того, как хотелось бы написать.

Answer (score 2):

Пример для JS:

```
// exclude every JS file that starts with a b except bad.js
gulp.src(['*.js', '!b*.js', 'bad.js'])
```

Или же раскидайте глобальные стили и стили для IE в разные папки, создайте два отдельный таска и подключайте необходимые стили для каждого из них.

Comment: Спасибо! Сложность, в том, что есть четкая структура проекта. Нужно собрать *-ie стили в один отдельно от общего .min.css. *-ie находятся в разных папках (модули) с другими файлами.

Comment: @CodeGust поправил

Comment: спасибо, но все сложнее... есть один-главный .styl файл проекта, в котором импортируются все стили проекта. уж очень много придется менять для такого способа решения проблемы, да и сомневаюсь это может быть одобрено...